# How to get the correct typing for overridden generic methods

Tags: python, mypy

I want to write a new container class. For this, the class inherits from collections.abc.Container.

Short reminder (this is what the container looks like):

```
@runtime_checkable
class Container(Protocol[_T_co]):
    @abstractmethod
    def __contains__(self, __x: object) -> bool: ...
```

That is what my first implementation looked like:

```
from collections.abc import Container
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

_ContainerType = TypeVar('_ContainerType')

class MyContainer(Container[_ContainerType], Generic[_ContainerType]):

    def _find(self, __value: _ContainerType) -> int:
        '''Returns the index of the specified element, or -1 if this container does not contain the element.'''
        return -1

    def __contains__(self, __x: _ContainerType) -> bool:
        return self._find(__x) >= 0
```

But running mypy (`mypy --strict --show-error-context .`) gave me the following output:

```
my_container.py: note: In member "__contains__" of class "MyContainer":
my_container.py:12: error: Argument 1 of "__contains__" is incompatible with supertype "Container"; supertype defines the argument type as "object"
my_container.py:12: note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
my_container.py:12: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides
```

Adapting the argument type to the base class type

```
    def __contains__(self, __x: object) -> bool:
        return self._find(__x) >= 0
```

results in another error:

```
my_container.py: note: In member "__contains__" of class "MyContainer":
my_container.py:13: error: Argument 1 to "_find" of "MyContainer" has incompatible type "object"; expected "_ContainerType"
```

Mypy is right on both cases. But how can I fix it?
(In other situations I use isinstance(...) to check the type. Then mypy accepts the Any -> <other_type> assignment. But I don't have a fix type here.)

Comment: `collections.abc.Container` only has one abstract method you have to implement. You could just not use `collections.abc.Container` and write the protocol yourself.

Comment: Right. But I have to say that the original code uses the `collection.abc.MutableSet`. This class inherits the method from the Container class. So I reduced the code to describe only the actual problem. With the other methods of the MutableSet (for example: `def add(self, value: _T) -> None:`), the arguments have the generic type `_T` and thus do not have the problem. That's why I skipped them.

Comment: And why don't you want `_find` to accept `object` as well? There's usually nothing wrong with trying to find `1` in `{'a', 'b'}` - here's why `__contains__` accepts `object`. Usually you don't have any additional assumptions (well, hash-based collections technically need a `Hashable`, but it's ignored everywhere, because it's too difficult for minor profit)

Comment: `_find` compares the values. Therefore the type is necessary. But you are right, if you make the used type `Hashable` then you can use the standard set. Your solution always works and so does the current solution too (if you use the right type). I'm more concerned with how to resolve the type conflict. It can always happen that the base class uses a type that is too general.